# Unexpected result while taking input from user through constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

This is my code. For any kind of input i get the output 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
I can't understand why?

```
import java.util.*;
class TestArray{
    int[] a=new int[10];
    TestArray(){
        for(int ele:a){
            Scanner src=new Scanner(System.in);
            ele=src.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
class TestArrayLoop{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestArray a=new TestArray();
        for(int ele:a.a){
            System.out.print(ele+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class is called `TestArray1`.

Comment: Add TestArray class code

Comment: I have made changes i stil get the same output @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: I have made changes i stil get the same output @Ugur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood how array element references work. You cannot use a `for`-each loop to change the values of elements in an array

In this code

```
for(int ele:a){
    Scanner src=new Scanner(System.in);
    ele=src.nextInt();
}
```

you are declaring a new variable `ele` which gets sets to each next value in the array. When you do

```
ele=src.nextInt();
```

you are changing the value of the variable, not the element in the array. Use a normal indexed for loop. And don't create a new `Scanner` object on each iteration.

```
Scanner src=new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   a[i] = src.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
    for(int ele:a){
        Scanner src=new Scanner(System.in);
        ele=src.nextInt();
    }
```

use traditional loop with indexing

Comment: `ele` is another variable than `a[i]`, though has the same value. When you assign to `ele`, `a` is not touched.